# Realizar una tabla de valores en phyton

Tags: python

Hola tengo un problema quisiera saber como hacer una formula que imprima una tabla de valores de una funcion lineal con while?

Comment: Bienvenido Ignacio!, te sugiero leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y tenga buenas respuestas, actualmente esta pregunta esta definida como "demasiado amplia" o "basada en opiniones", debes ser más especifico. También, aprovecha y realiza el [tour] para entender mejor el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Creo entender a lo que te refieres, ¿quieres imprimir una gráfica a partir de una función lineal?, si es así, te recomiendo utilizar [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) ya que es una librería bastante completa que te permite realizar gráficas a partir de valores.

A continuación te dejo un ejemplo de como graficar una función lineal y una cuadrática con el mismo.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
**

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    from matplotlib import pyplot
    # Función cuadrática.
    def f1(x):
        return 2*(x**2) + 5*x - 2
    # Función lineal.
    def f2(x):
        return 4*x + 1
    # Valores del eje X que toma el gráfico.
    x = range(-10, 15)
    # Graficar ambas funciones.
    pyplot.plot(x, [f1(i) for i in x])
    pyplot.plot(x, [f2(i) for i in x])
    # Establecer el color de los ejes.
    pyplot.axhline(0, color="black")
    pyplot.axvline(0, color="black")
    # Limitar los valores de los ejes.
    pyplot.xlim(-10, 10)
    pyplot.ylim(-10, 10)
    # Guardar gráfico como imágen PNG.
    pyplot.savefig("output.png")
    # Mostrarlo.
    pyplot.show()
```

**

Comment: Gracias por responder

Comment: De nada, te recomiendo formular de una mejor manera tu pregunta para obtener mejores respuesta al respecto.